# Full Screen Android App feature

Tags: java, android

I am new to Android Development. I implemented an option in my android app for switching between FULL SCREEN and Normal Screen. Below is my code to do that. But I have experience one problem. When I Switch my app to Full Screen mode, all SCROLL VIEWS on my activity stops scrolling. And when I switch back to normal screen all Scroll Views work fine. Help me.

```
//Shared Preferences
    SharedPreferences screenPreference = getSharedPreferences("MyAppSettings", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int ScreenFlag = screenPreference.getInt("ScreenFlag", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = screenPreference.edit();
    switch(ScreenFlag)
    {
    case 0:     //set preference ScreenFlag, app running first time
    case 2:     //Full screen - OFF
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        editor.putInt("ScreenFlag", 2);
        editor.commit();
        break;
    case 1:     //Full screen - ONN
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);
        editor.putInt("ScreenFlag", 1);
        editor.commit();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //end - Shared Preferences
```